# add elsarticle class to texstudio

Tags: document-classes, texstudio, elsarticle

My question is generally about adding `elsarticle` document class to TeXStudio.
In the installation documents it says that I should download `.ins` and `.dtx` files and compile them with latex. I don't know what it exactly mean.

What I could do was to compile `ecrc-template.tex` with TexStudio and start writing inside it. But, without the template, I could not add this class to TeXStudio.

I'd be grateful if you kindly help me with this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: TeXStudio is just a front end. Which TeX distribution do you use: TeXLive, MacTeX, MikTeX, or something else entirely?

Comment: I use TeXLive. Sorry not to mention it.

Comment: Since you use TeXLive, the `elsarticle` document class should already be installed unless you chose some nonstandard installation procedure. Do you know how to run the `tlmgr` utililty? It should provide a bullet-proof way of installing and updating packages.

Comment: That's strange. I installed TeXLive through a DVD I got from the university but tlmgr is not included in the package I installed!!!

Comment: @Mico I could locate tlmgr and I put it in the path. But, using the following command: tlmgr  --self --all update, I receive the following message: tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository
http://ctan.asis.io/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
  (2014--2014)
do not include the version of the local installation
  (2013).

Comment: Looks like you have an out-of-date and incomplete version of TeXlive. Is installing TeXlive2014 -- available on the Iternet -- at all an option for you?

Comment: I have a very poor connection to internet. I changed the repository through: tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2013/tlnet-final
and then updated all with: tlmgr update --all
It should have solved the problem, but still no elsarticle class in texlive

Comment: Just to verify --  what, if anything -- does the instruction `kpsewhich elsarticle.cls` typed in a command window return?

Comment: @mico, please forgive me for my late return. The command you said returns: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls

Comment: @user63380 - In that case, `elsarticle.cls` would appear to be installed already.